# Where to Find this file "firebase.json"

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

### unable to find the file 'firebase.json'.

I am adding multi path prefix in firebase dynamic links. It's saying to add prefix, you need to add this snippet in 'firebase.json' but I am unable to find this file.

[image is for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZnhI.png)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

When you run command `firebase init` then it will generate a file **firebase.json** . and this file is under root of your project or for better understanding it is locate at parallel to pubspec.yaml file

Comment: can you please attach screenshot for better understanding, Thanks :)

Comment: Yes , Find the Screenshot above answer